# Python body.encode( ) Javascript alternative

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sha256, plaid

I'm trying to verify a webhook coming from Plaid in NodeJS by calculating the Sha256 of the webhook body and I'm following a Python code [here](https://support.plaid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041410794) where the code is showing :

```
   # Compute the has of the body.
   m = hashlib.sha256()
   m.update(body.encode())
   body_hash = m.hexdigest()
```

What's the alternative of body.encode() in Javascript before passing it to the Sha256 function please ? Note that the body I'm getting is an object containing the following data :

> { error: null,   item_id: '4zAGyokJ1XiWP63QNl1RuLZV76o55nudVXzNG',
>   new_transactions: 0,   webhook_code: 'DEFAULT_UPDATE',   webhook_type:
>   'TRANSACTIONS' }

However I'm trying to get this hash :

> b05ef560b59e8d8e427433c5e0f6a11579b5dfe6534257558b896f858007385a

Comment: You're supposed to hash the body bytes of the webhook, not the object you've decoded from JSON. You already have an "object", so you've gone too far there.

Comment: How to get the body bytes of the webhook please ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

So, if the body is JSON **(NOT JSON STRING)** then you need to stringify it and put it in the `.update` function As the `m.body` takes a string. If you have your body as **STRING** then just put it in as is.

This is from the Crypto Example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

const stringBody = JSON.stringify(body);
hash.update(stringBody);
console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
```

**Edit:**
If the hash is not same then maybe you need to correct the newlines or whitespaces. You need to make both bodies exactly the same. Here In the below example I am using same exact string and encoding using Python AND NodeJS.

```
import hashlib
body = '{"error":null,"item_id":"4zAGyokJ1XiWP63QNl1RuLZV76o55nudVXzNG","new_transactions":0,"webhook_code":"DEFAULT_UPDATE","webhook_type":"TRANSACTIONS"}'
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(body.encode())
body_hash = m.hexdigest()
print(body_hash)
```

**Output:**

```
python3 file.py
26f1120ccaf99a383b7462b233e18994d0c06d4585e3fe9a91a449e97a1c03ba
```

**And Using NodeJS:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
const body = {
  error: null,
  item_id: '4zAGyokJ1XiWP63QNl1RuLZV76o55nudVXzNG',
  new_transactions: 0,
  webhook_code: 'DEFAULT_UPDATE',
  webhook_type: 'TRANSACTIONS'
}

const stringBody = JSON.stringify(body);
hash.update(stringBody);
console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
```

**Output:**

```
node file.js
26f1120ccaf99a383b7462b233e18994d0c06d4585e3fe9a91a449e97a1c03ba
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but even with JSON.stringify(body) I didn't got the same hash

Comment: Edited the answer to add comparison.